# Bubble animation in android

Tags: android

Need to implement a bubble graph in Android. When the screen is launched the bubbles should emerge from a particular point in the screen and later should get scattered across the screen. The bubbles ideally should have a glossy appearance with an image present on it. The size of each bubble depends on the weightage/importance of each image.

Are there any libraries readily available by which this can be accomplished. If not how should I go about implementing this.

Comment: Are you using QT's QML and QtQuick for the front end?

Comment: No. I do not use any of the aforementioned